# Setting different margins automatically according to page numbers?

Tags: margins

I am new at Latex. Recently I have learned how to set margins in some short articles. But now I have a very long article, which has more than 70 pages. I want to make it to be like every three pages has one same margin different from the rest of pages.

Like Pages 1-3 have margins 0.1cm. Pages 4-6 have margins 0.2cm. Pages 7-9 have margins 0.3cm. and so on

Now I was wondering if there is any way I can set those margins automaticaly? Thanks

Comment: you can not change the margins at automatic page breaks as a paragraph needs a known text width for line breaking. If you have a forced page break, eg `\chapter` every three pages, then it is relatively easy/

Comment: But it also doesn't easy to insert so many page breaks manually. If you know there is any way to do those settings under some special conditions(I think the ifthen package can do something in it, but I haven't figured it out), that would be really appreciated @DavidCarlisle

Comment: No it is not possible to do this at an automatic page break. ifthen package can not help (trust me, I wrote it)